# Query to count rows and more specific rows in one table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a single query that returns me how many times a user has bought a product, and how many time the product has been bought.

The table i'm searching from has the columns

```
log_id (int)
log_product (int)
log_date (datetime)
log_user (int)
```

Today, I'm using this code

```
SELECT product_id
     , product_name
     , brand_name
     , COUNT(log_user) nbuys 
  FROM Products p
  JOIN Brands b
    ON p.product_id = b.brands_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN log l
    ON l.log_product = p.product_id 
 GROUP 
    BY p.product_id
```

And the return is something like:

```
| product_id | product_name | brand_name | nbuys |
```

Where nbuys is the number of times the product has been bought, by all users. What I want is a way to rewrite that query so it returns me something like:

```
| product_id | product_name | brand_name | nbuys | n_userbuys |
```

Where the new column, 'n_userbuys', is the number of times the user who is seeing the page has bought that. So an user_id info will be placed on the query. The final result is a list where all the products can be seen.

I hope this is clear.

---

I'm adding the structures of the tables Products and Brands to the question.

Product

```
| product_id (int) | product_name (varchar) |  product_brand (int) |
```

Brand

```
| brand_id (int) | brand_name (varchar) |
```

---

I think I was not clear on what I'm looking for. the table `log` just put together some keys from other tables. The query I'm trying to write is supposed to create a list. On that list, all the products shall appear. On each line, the number of times a product has been purchased must be shown. This is well accomplished by `COUNT(log_user) ... GROUP BY p.product_id`. The missing part is that each line must also show how many times a given user has bought it.

That means that if an user with user_id=7 is viewing the page, the list generated through the query should show something like:

```
| product_id | product_name | brand_name | nbuys | n_userbuys |
|      1     |  pencil      |  Faber     | 120   |     12     |
|      2     |  pen         |  Bic       | 531   |     34     |
|      3     |  rubber      |  Faber     | 60    |     4      |
```

But if another user, with user_id=8, is viewing the page, the list should keep the values on column nbuys, but change the ones on column n_userbuys to the number of times user_id=8 bought them:

```
| product_id | product_name | brand_name | nbuys | n_userbuys |
|      1     |  pencil      |  Faber     | 120   |     1      |
|      2     |  pen         |  Bic       | 531   |     23     |
|      3     |  rubber      |  Faber     | 60    |     1      |
```

The code is running on php, so I can just add the user id to the query wherever it is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do u identify the user? nothing in ur query involves the user on the page.

Comment: The code runs on php. user is identified by session and passed inside the query thought a variable, like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id=$user"

Comment: show the structure of **Brands** and **Product** tables

Comment: right, but how do you identify the user in your *query*? you mention `log_users` in the table you're "searching", however in your query you use `log_buys` which doesnt exist in the list provided. perhaps a full DDL of the table would help us.

Comment: The table 'log' has the following columns log_id, log_product, log_date and log_user.  Each time a purchase is made, it adds the product_id, the date, and the user_id related to the purchase to the table. The goal is to print a list using that table, from where it should count how many times each product_id appear on all it rows, and how many times each product_id appears associated to a given user_id

Comment: please when showing table structure show the column types also in next question if be, what's the type of product_brand? I mean what will be the join column between product and brand tables?

Comment: I've changed the question to replace `log_buys` for `log_user` @PlantTheIdea

Comment: I've added the column types to the question @FarhangAmary

Comment: great, so your join condition (`JOIN Brands b ON p.product_id =b.brands_id`) in your query is incorrect, I corrected it too in my answer, the tables should be joined on base of **brand_id** not **Product_id**

Comment: I've just tried you code. It works fine, but we are aiming for different goals. Your code returns me how many times an item has been sold and how many users has bought it. What I'm looking for is how many times an item has been sold and how many times the user logged in has bought it. I added some information on the question to try to make it clear. Thanks in advance! @FarhangAmary

Comment: Still struggling? If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry. I'd solved the problem and posted it. I will follow your recommendations in futures questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost found an answer to my question:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name, brand_name, COUNT(log_user) AS nlog, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN log_user='$user_id' THEN 1 END) as ulog FROM Products 
INNER JOIN Brands ON Products.product_brand=Brands.brand_id 
LEFT JOIN log on log.log_product = Product.product_id 
GROUP BY product_id,product_name, Brands_name
```

Using `COUNT(CASE WHEN log_user='$user_id' THEN 1 END)` allows me to count how many times a row exists with that specific condition. However, the code is duplicating the lines by the number of time each user has bought an item.

---

Solved. The fix is to just GROUP BY product_id. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

on base of question detail and your comments under it, you need to just add `LOG_USER` to the select staement, also you have to correct the `group by` clause

```
SELECT product_id, product_name, brand_name, 
  COUNT(log_buys) AS nbuys, LOG_USER AS n_userbuys FROM Products INNER 
  JOIN Brands ON Products.product_brand=Brands.brands_id LEFT JOIN
  log on log.log_product = Products.product_id 
  GROUP BY product_id,product_name, brand_name,LOG_USER
```

Comment: But how, on that code, I will specify the user_id I'm wanting to count? I mean, it should count how many times the product has been bought and how many times the user who is viewing the page has bought it. Probably, we will need to add the user_id we are looking for somewhere in the query.

Comment: if your `LOG_USER` does not contains `user_id` then of course you need to add it.

Comment: Thats what I don't know how to do. I thought it would be some WHERE code on this, like WHERE log.log_user = '2'.

Comment: (I edited the answer)you don't need to that where clause if you want to list the number of buys for all users, just add the user_log to the selection and also add it to the group by clause and for the name of the user you can join above selection to users table